# Unable to see Signature block in a Signed PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, digital-signature

I was working on PowerShell since last 3+ years. Earlier, when you open a digitally signed script in Notepad, it use to show the Signature block at end of the script file.

For example (this screen-shot):
[image: Signature block in a Signed Script]

However, I have observed that it is not showing the signature block at end of the file anymore. I don't know if that is due to the new version of Windows (currently I am switched to Windows 10) or for some other reason.

Now, even a signed script doesn't show the signature block at it's end, when you open it. But, I can still verify the signature using `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` Cmdlet.

Can someone please help me understand why I can't see the signature block in a digitally signed script anymore.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Signed script has block (and can view it in notepad on Win10/PS5.1). Removed block = Removed Digital Signatures in properties and `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` says "Status: NotSigned"

Comment: Exactly. I have checked on my colleagues' machine with same version of PowerShell (5) but Windows 7, There he can see the signature block visible at bottom of the Script. But, I can't see the signature block even for signed scripts. Not sure how to fix this :-(